# Backpropagation Through Time (BPTT) of LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, backpropagation, lstm

I am currently trying to understand the BPTT for LSTM in TensorFlow. I get that the parameter "num_steps" is used for the range that the RNN is rolled out and the Error backpropagated. I got a general question of how this works.

For reference a repitition of the formulas. I'm referring to:
[Formulas LSTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zKXt.png) (https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.00019)

**Question:**
What paths are backpropagated that many steps? The constant error carousel is created by the formula 5, and the derivate for backpropagation (s(t)->s(t-1)) is 1 for all timesteps. This is why LSTMs capture long range dependencies. I get confused with the dependencies of g(t), i(t), f(t) and o(t) of h(t-1). In words: The current gates do not just depend on the input, but also on the last hidden state.

**Doesn't this dependency lead to the exploding/vanishing gradients problem again?**

If I backpropagate along these connections I get gradients that are not one. Peephole connections essentially lead to the same problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe a better fit for http://stats.stackexchange.com or http://datascience.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks, I also posted it there: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15444/backpropagation-through-time-bptt-of-lstm-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

**I finally found the answer myself:**

In the original paper of LSTMs (https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjOybDTstDQAhWJiywKHVigAioQFgg6MAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeeplearning.cs.cmu.edu%2Fpdfs%2FHochreiter97_lstm.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGoFvqrva4rDCNIcqNe_SiPL_VPxg) it is said (in chapter 4, page 7) that:

"**Learning.** We use a variant of RTRL (e.g., Robinson and Fallside 1987) which properly takes into account the altered, multiplicative dynamics caused by input and output gates. However, to ensure non-decaying error backprop through internal states of memory cells, as with truncated BPTT (e.g., Williams and Peng 1990), errors arriving at \memory cell net inputs" (for cell cj , this includes netcj , netinj , netoutj ) do not get propagated back further in time (although they do serve to change the incoming weights). Only within2 memory cells, errors are propagated back through previous internal states scj ."

So essentially: backpropagation through time concerning the internal state is done, but other complex dependencies are not backpropagated

Comment: That was back then. Today with Theano/TensorFlow/Pytorch/Chainer/CNTK/you-name-it, no special treatment is given and everything is backpropagated. Also, note that while an individual cell's design follows the original paper, design of an LSTM  layer has been re-thinked (greatly simplified IMHO).